# advance time artificially in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I have code that depends on elapsed time (for instance: If 10 minutes has passed)

What is the best way to simulate this in pytest?
Monkey patching methods in module time?

Example code (the tested code - a bit schematic but conveys the message):

```
current_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
retry_time = current_time + datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)
#time_in_db represents time extracted from DB
if time_in_db > retry_time:
    #perform the retry
```

Comment: Can you show a snippet of your code? I'm curious to know what you are using. I just want to make sure I have a proper understanding of what you are asking.

Comment: edited the original question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[FreezeGun](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun/) is probably the easiest solution.

Sample code from its readme:

```
from freezegun import freeze_time

@freeze_time("2012-01-14")
def test():
    assert datetime.datetime.now() == datetime.datetime(2012, 01, 14)
```

Comment: I was just writing something up using mock.patch. Nevermind! This is great!

Comment: but what if the datetime is in the production code (and not the test code)?

Comment: @Boaz - As long as FreezeGun is active, it will affect both production code and test code. Or am I misunderstanding your question?